# How to get the name by id when a field is selected from a drop down list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am having a drop down, where I have to select a category and print the details.
This is my view:

```
= select_tag 'category_id',options_from_collection_for_select(Category.by_account(current_account).by_type("Customer").active.all, :id, :name, params[:category_id]),include_blank: true, class: 'form-control'
```

In model:

```
  def cat_name
    #Category.find(@params[:category_id])
    @params[:category_id]
  end
```

and in my report view:

```
<%= report.cat_name %>
```

It is displaying the category_id fine, but if I want to list the name, it is not showing.
I tried `<%= report.cat_name.try(:name) %>` but didn't helped me.

Please tell where it is going wrong?

Comment: What is `@params`, `report`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are  ways:
1. The way @Nikola Todorovic mentioned is right.

Controller:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
```

View:

```
<%= @category.name %>
```

As you said, it is displaying nothing, you can try the second one:

Take another method:

```
  def display_category_name
    unless cat_name.nil? || cat_name.blank?
      Category.find_by_id(cat_name).name
    else
      "None"
    end
  end
```

In view:

I have done this second method while generating reports.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
```

View:

```
<%= @category.name %>
```

Comment: It is displaying nothing